# building go package using docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize the go package that I found here...

https://github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch

The docker image is much more convenient than installing go on all the servers. But the following dockerfile is not working.

```
FROM golang:1.6-onbuild

RUN go get github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch
RUN make

RUN ./bin/go-mysql-elasticsearch -config=./etc/river.toml
```

How do I build a go package directly from github using a concise dockerfile?

---

Update

https://hub.docker.com/r/eaglechen/go-mysql-elasticsearch/

I found the exact dockerfile that would do this. But the docker command mentioned on that page does not work. It does not start the go package nor does it start the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "not working", but RUN ./bin/... means RUN from the current working directory ([`/go/src/app` in `golang/1.6/onbuild/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/ce284e14cdee73fbaa8fb680011a812f272eae2e/1.6/onbuild/Dockerfile#L4)).

And [go build in Makefile](https://github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch/blob/master/Makefile#L6) would put the binary in

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch/bin/...
```

So you need to add to your Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do what I am looking for.

https://github.com/EagleChen/docker_go_mysql_elasticsearch

And I hope one day I will learn to use that little search box.